# Eagle-Show all connections?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am trying to "light" all the net labels that are connected together , to see if everything is right.

So for example if one pin of a resistor called **"R_A"**  and another pin on some other chip called **"R_A"** , i would like to push something in Eagle to see both of them(and all other labels with the same name) in some bold color/light .

How would you do that in Eagle ?

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use show and double click on the Net/Wire, then all pins will be red, the names black and the nets will be light green

Comment: Great thanks it worked although tou barely see it. Is there a way to check errors also in my circuit(not pcb) ?

Comment: Also ,why its not working between pages?? If i show in page 1 connection i wouldnt see it in page 2..

Comment: Chechking if its right would work with either ERC or you looking if something is connected wrong. Seems like its generally not working between pages, sorry :C

Comment: You can also type ```show net``` into the command box (where 'net' is the name of the net you want to show)

Comment: also use show ~ netname to get all pages (case insensitive)

Answer (score 4):

> Use show and double click on the Net/Wire, then all pins will be red,
>   the names black and the nets will be light green

Go to Options > Set... > colors > high contrasts to make the connections pop out more